# how to append divs to a specific div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically fadeIn divs with a specific height and width and the same Id to a specific div with class `myBox` and randomly position them in `myBox` using the `append()` function. However divs are being appended inside and outside `myBox`.

This is my code. What is wrong?

```js
var xx = Math.random() * 100;
for (var i = 0; i < xx; i++) {
  var $newdiv1 = $("<div id='object1' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red ;'></div>");
  var top = Math.random() * 700 - 30;
  var left = Math.random() * 1200;

  $($newdiv1).css({
    "top": top,
    "left": left
  });

  $($newdiv1).css('background-color', getRandomColor);
  $(".myBox").append($newdiv1).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Comment: An element can only be appended to one position in the DOM, so the phrasing “are being appended inside and outside” makes rather little sense. You might have an optical effect here that is different from what you want, but it is hard to tell with this snippet only - so please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pkh9Lr7y/. Can you give some more detail on what the exact issue is. The duplicated `id` attributes will be an issue later though.

Comment: Guess it depends on the dimensions of your `.myBox` element, whether those randomly placed elements appear “inside” or “outside”. Since your max left coordinate value is 1200px and your boxes are 100px wide, your container element of course would have to be at least 1300px wide to contain all possible placements in that direction …

Comment: Please fix the title of your question, it is not relative to the actual question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reviewing your question I think Rory's comment gives you the answer, but I just enhaced it. Need to set `overflow: hidden` property of css on main div to stop showing the child objects outside of main div.

Please review the snippet, or [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w4amk1gL/). Just added background color and opacity for better presentation.

```js
$(function(){
var xx = Math.random() * 100;
for (var i = 0; i < xx; i++) {
  var $newdiv1 = $("<div id='object1' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red ;'></div>");
  var top = Math.random() * 700 - 30;
  var left = Math.random() * 1200;

  $($newdiv1).css({
    "top": top,
    "left": left
  });

  $($newdiv1).css('background-color', '#C00'); //getRandomColor);
  $(".myBox").append($newdiv1).fadeIn("slow");
}
});
```

```css
.myBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.myBox div {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myBox"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Appending seems to be done correctly, but the first problem I can see here is that you are setting top and left attributes, but position attribute is not set.
You should add to your stylesheet something that will specify position attribute for the main container and child divs.
Example:

```
.myBox {
  position: absolute;
}

.myBox div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also another thing. You specify $newdiv1 as jQuery object:

```
var $newdiv1 = $(...)
```

And then you again wrap it with $(). This should be enough:

```
$newdiv1.css({
    "top": top,
    "left": left
  });
$newdiv1.css('background-color', getRandomColor);
```